# Do we have to write reactive code inside WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I know that a reactive controller should return a `Flux<T>` or `Mono<T>`, which means it's reactive on http handler level.

But if we **do an external http call** in a controller with **non-reactive** code, which have to wait a long time IO until that http call response, what will happen if 10000 users use http to call this controller at the same time? Let's assume there is only **one** thread to handle the code inside controller, so will **more** requests be handled during the IO?

If no, do we **have to** use reactive code such as `WebClient` and `ReactiveRepository`  to call external http API and CRUD on DB?

If yes, how can that be implemented? Because it's just lines of non-reactive code, how Java know like "hey, it's waiting for response, let's handle another event first"?

Comment: [reactive-streams-jvm#term_non-obstructing](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#term_non-obstructing)

Comment: [Reactive to Blocking](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/929/reactive-programming-with-reactor-3/ReactiveToBlocking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing blocking I/O within a reactive pipeline (e.g. a reactive controller method) is forbidden; doing so can lead to serious problems at runtime or even terminal errors if a `block` operator is used.

Reactor provides infrastructure to wrap blocking calls and schedule that work on specific threads. See the [How do I wrap a synchronous, blocking call](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) section in the reactor reference documentation. Doing that will work but is likely to have a negative effect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I did an experiment myself, looks like we have to use reactive code inside WebFlux so that everything is reactive and the performance is really high